# Where to apply input source to common gate configuration

Tags: mosfet, analog, integrated-circuit, configuration, common-gate

I have learned from my teacher that the input of the common gate is applied at the source pin and the output voltage is probed from the drain pin, why not vice versa? Can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because the bulk/body diode within and part-of the MOSFET will turn it into a diode rather than a MOSFET. I don't see any functionality here that then couldn't be replaced by a diode.